# ¿Por qué no se agrega el control ReportViewer?

Tags: reportviewer, visual-studio-2019

Actualmente trabajo en Visual Studio 2019, cuando quiero agregar un control ReportViewer dentro del formulario, este se agrega en la barra inferior y no se muestra.

E intentado agregar el control desde extensiones y actualizaciones, agregando el diseñador de informes RDLC de Microsoft. También desde el administrador de paquetes NuGet agregando Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms y luego agregando su libreria al proyecto pero en ambos casos el resultado es el mismo, no se visualiza el control.

[image: Anexo imagen]

De antemano Gracias.

Comment: Me ocurre exactamente lo mismo, no aparece el control ReportViewer en el formulario, solamente aparece en la parte de abajo, pero no sirve para nada. Ni siquiera se puede asociar a un formulario creado. Si por un casual, has descubierto como solucionarlo, te agradecería que explicaras como. Gracias.

Comment: Hola Chiwi, ReportViewr da problemas cada vez que Microsoft saca una nueva version de VS . Te recomiendo echarle un ojo a este video que explican como solucionar tu problema. Si te sirve avisame luego desarrollo una  respuesta para este hilo. [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qhcg4dy43xk)

Comment: Gracias por responder. Acabo de ver el video y haciendolo como dice, ahora, al pegar el control en el form, me da este error: Error al crear el componente 'ReportViewer'. El mensaje de error es el siguiente:
'System.IO.FileNotFoundException: No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado' 
Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,

Comment: lo mismo me paso al descargar la version 12, y tengo el mismo problema.

Comment: Por favor no uses la zona de respuestas para exponer dudas, comentarios o aclaraciones, lee [answer] y si necesitas apoyo entonces checa [ask] y abre una nueva pregunta

Answer (score 0):

instala el RDLC en las extenciones de VS

instala en tu proyecto a traves del Administardor de paquetes de nuget

> Microsoft.ReportViewer.winForms.V12 
>   compila,y debera aparecer en el cuadro de herrameientas la carpeta Microsft SQL Server, q contiene el control ReportViewer, al agregar el control a cualquier form no aparecera nada

Por ultimo instala tambien a traves de Admon. de NuGet en tu proyecto

> Microsoft.ReportServices.ReportcViewerControl.WinForms, pedira permisos para instalar libreriras adicionales aceptalas

Vuelve a compilar y listo, ya podras agregar el control ReportViewer desde el cuadro de herramientas, de la misma carpeta Microsoft SQL Server, ahora si aparecera en el form

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Af2Lh5RMOVM